# WindowsFormsHost layout issue

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, windowsformshost

I have embedded a Windows Forms application in a WPF browser application using WindowsFormsHost control, and the size of the form always comes a bit short (about 10px). During debug I noticed that the form height and width is 10 pixels less than the actual form height and width. So I tried manually setting the height and the width by adding 10px to the `mainForm.Width` and `mainForm.Height` but then it cuts off the edges and makes it worse. Is there a different way to set the actual width/height?

```
WindowsFormsHost windowsFormsHost = new WindowsFormsHost();
        //stackPanel.Width = mainForm.Width;
        //stackPanel.Height = mainForm.Height;
        //windowsFormsHost.Width = mainForm.Width;
        //windowsFormsHost.Height = mainForm.Height;
        mainForm.TopLevel = false;
        windowsFormsHost.Child = mainForm;
        stackPanel.Children.Add(windowsFormsHost);
```

Here is the XAML code:

```
<Page x:Class="WPFHost.Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Title="Page1">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,10,10" Name="stackPanel" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Screenshots:

The actual form:

[image]

How it is displayed on WPF

[image]

Comment: Show the `xaml` code as well. and a screenshot if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your `Margin`. You're decreasing it by 10px in the margin, and then you increase the height and width of both `Stackpanel` and `WindowsFormsHost`. But due to `Margin` this manually setting of height and width doesn't effect on the `StackPanel` and only increases the size of the `WindowsFormsHost` and it goes out of the edges.

I marked the margin by **Red Color**:

[image]

Just remove the margin or set it to zero:

```
<StackPanel Margin="0" Name="stackPanel" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Also set the `Height` and `Width` in C# (they'll effect now):

```
WindowsFormsHost windowsFormsHost = new WindowsFormsHost();

stackPanel.Width = mainForm.Width;
stackPanel.Height = mainForm.Height;

windowsFormsHost.Width = mainForm.Width;
windowsFormsHost.Height = mainForm.Height;
```